# Variable band sizes with ordinal scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to create an ordinal axis with varying sizes of rangeRounds or bands. Its fairly straight forward to do this using a linear axis but wondered if it where possible to do this with an ordinal axis. I wondered if I use range and have explicit values, but can't seem to make that work either.
I'm trying to create this kind of thing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get variable bands with a band scale (`d3.scaleBand()`). However, getting variable intervals with a regular ordinal scale (`d3.scaleOrdinal()`) is quite trivial.

For instance:

```
var scale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["Lemons", "Oranges", "Pears", "Apples", "Bananas"])
  .range([10, 40, 100, 150, 180, 290]);
```

The only complicated thing is moving the ticks to the center of the axis... but it's not that complicated:

```
axisGroup.selectAll("text").each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(0," + (scale.range()[i + 1] - scale(d)) / 2 + ")")
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["Lemons", "Oranges", "Pears", "Apples", "Bananas"])
  .range([10, 40, 100, 150, 180, 290]);

var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(scale.domain())
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return scale(d)
  })
  .attr("height", function(d, i) {
    return scale.range()[i + 1] - scale(d)
  })
  .style("fill", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", 2)

var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale);

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
  .call(axis);

gY.selectAll("text").each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(0," + (scale.range()[i + 1] - scale(d)) / 2 + ")")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg height=300></svg>
```

Comment: Must have been doing something wrong as I thought I'd tried that. Many thanks